# Replacing a value on a page with a higher value

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say we have this snippet of code on a site

```
<p> 30.24 </p>
```

How could I manage to use jQuery to change the value of any number under 60 with a random number between 70 and 120 and optionally a decimal?

Comment: that you already tried?

Comment: How are you going to work out which `<p>` tags to change?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (and maybe [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/))

Comment: I would like to change all values on that page that are under 60.

Comment: What is a "number"? A number that is the entire content of a `<p>` element, or a number anywhere in the text including in, say, `<div>This is some text with a number like 30.24 so it should change.</div>`

Comment: Yes in a post like that.

Comment: @RuslanGrebeniouk I updated my answer to handle the situation you have described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all of the `p` elements on the page using jQuery.  Then provide an anonymous function to the `html` function to change the value of each number.

```
$("p").text(function(i,text){
    if(isNaN(text)){
        return;
    } 
    var value = parseFloat(text);
    if(value >= 0 && value > 20 &&  value < 60){
        var replacement = (Math.random() * 51 + 70) + "";
        return replacement.substring(0,(replacement > 100) ? 6:5);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VnHh6/3/

After reading your comments it appears you want to replace these numbers surrounded by some text.  The code above will not satisfy this need.  Consider using the code below if you must replace numbers surrounded by text.

```
$("p").text(function(i,text){
    var regex = new RegExp('(\\d+(?:.\\d{2})?)', 'g');
    var matches = text.match(regex);

    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
        var value = parseFloat(matches[i]);
        if(value >= 0 && value > 20 &&  value < 60){
            text = text.replace(matches[i], (Math.random() * 51 + 70).toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    return text;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VnHh6/5/

Comment: And what if I wanted to exclude 0 - 20?

Comment: So don't change numbers between 0 and 20?

Comment: Could any downvoters please explain their reasoning?  I would like to improve this code.

Comment: I did not downvote, however there's a few things wrong. `120 - 70` should be `120 - 70 + 1` and anyway it should just be `51`. Also the OP wanted to exclude from `0` to `20` in the comments, so it should be `>= 0`. Comparing string to numbers multiple times results in multiple coercions. It's probably better to simply parse `html` to a number once using `parseFloat` and it's also better to use `text()` over `html()` anyway. You can also just use `someFloatNum.toFixed(2)` to get two decimals. `toFixed` returns a string as well, so you can get rid of the `+ ""` hack ;)

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the `toFixed` suggestion. It really tidied up the code.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Why you need `value >= 0` when `value > 20`.

Comment: @Enve See the comments where the OP wants to ignore values between 0 and 20.

Comment: `value > 20` ignores from `(-infinity, 20)`, doesn't it?
So there is no need for `value >= 0`

Comment: They want to change all numbers less than 60 and ignore those between 0 and 20.  So `value >= 0 && value > 20` excludes that range.

Comment: `value >= 0 && value > 20` and `value > 20` are the same. 

What you wrote in previous comment is about numbers `(-infinity,0] && (20,60)`.

That can be done by this code `if((value < 60) && !(value>=0 && value <20))`

Comment: `value >= 0 && value > 20` and `value > 20` are not the same since the latter does not include negative numbers.

Comment: Then `value > 20 && value < 60` does the job

Answer (score 0):

```
var rand = function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 51 + 70);
}

if(parseFloat($('p').text())<60){
    $('p').text(rand())
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JnfjP/1/)